# Sort data.frame algorithm R

Tags: r

I have my data.frame sample:

```
Time EventName
1 2015-08-02 09:09:22 logged_in
2 2015-08-02 09:35:38 deauthorize
3 2015-08-02 09:36:06 logged_in
4 2015-08-02 09:40:42 deauthorize
5 2015-08-02 09:40:48 logged_in
6 2015-08-02 09:42:46 deauthorize
7 2015-08-02 09:43:15 deauthorize
8 2015-08-02 09:44:49 deauthorize
9 2015-08-02 09:48:06 logged_in
10 2015-08-02 09:49:43 logged_in
11 2015-08-02 10:12:07 logged_in
12 2015-08-02 11:46:15 deauthorize
```

I want to stay only pairs `logged_in` and `deauthorize` (I need it for calculation time between logs `logged_in` and `deauthorize`, but some logs was lost). So I want my table after sort looks like:

```
Time      EventName
1 2015-08-02 09:09:22 logged_in
2 2015-08-02 09:35:38 deauthorize
3 2015-08-02 09:36:06 logged_in
4 2015-08-02 09:40:42 deauthorize
5 2015-08-02 09:40:48 logged_in
6 2015-08-02 09:42:46 deauthorize
11 2015-08-02 10:12:07 logged_in
12 2015-08-02 11:46:15 deauthorize
```

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to solve this? Why did it not work?

Comment: I'm a complete beginner so could you at least advise me what to start with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
end <- which(c(0,diff(as.numeric(df$EventName))) == -1)
df[sort(c(end-1,end)),]
#                   Time   EventName
# 1  2015-08-02 09:09:22   logged_in
# 2  2015-08-02 09:35:38 deauthorize
# 3  2015-08-02 09:36:06   logged_in
# 4  2015-08-02 09:40:42 deauthorize
# 5  2015-08-02 09:40:48   logged_in
# 6  2015-08-02 09:42:46 deauthorize
# 11 2015-08-02 10:12:07   logged_in
# 12 2015-08-02 11:46:15 deauthorize
```

This is a `base R` solution using R's factor coercion. We locate the instances of `"deauthorize"` by using factors to our advantage. Usually they are a pain but in this case being able to quickly turn the `EventName` column into a series of 1's and 2's helps quicken the search. Check `as.numeric(df$EventName)` for reference.

With this index we then need to find cases of a 1 followed by a 2. An efficient way to do that is to find the difference of each element. `diff(as.numeric(df$EventName))` does that for us. you can imagine which value of that vector will target the case we are looking for, `-1`.

**Data**

```
df  <- structure(list(Time = c("2015-08-02 09:09:22", "2015-08-02 09:35:38", 
"2015-08-02 09:36:06", "2015-08-02 09:40:42", "2015-08-02 09:40:48", 
"2015-08-02 09:42:46", "2015-08-02 09:43:15", "2015-08-02 09:44:49", 
"2015-08-02 09:48:06", "2015-08-02 09:49:43", "2015-08-02 10:12:07", 
"2015-08-02 11:46:15"), EventName = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("deauthorize", "logged_in"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Time", "EventName"), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not working when table starts from "deauthorize". How can I fix it? I need my table starts from Logged_in

Comment: Can you add an example to your quesiton?

Comment: Try adding this line before the others `df$EventName <- factor(as.character(df$EventName), levels=c("logged_in", "deauthorize"))`